# is there a way to compile graphs from pages inside an app and post the collected graphs to another page inside the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graph, pdfkit, wicked-pdf

In an ROR app I'm building I would like to let the user choose some graphs on a page inside the app and display the chosen graphs on another page inside the app.

I'm using `chartkick` to render the graphs. and the plan is to use the `wickedpdf`gem or the `PDFKit` to print the chosen graphs from the `graph page``

I haven't started building it yet, but I would like to know if someone have done this kind of function and could perhaps share his/her experience.

Comment: personally never worked with graphs, but you can save in db as a json and render `_graph_xxxx` in the page.

Comment: I know people have had success using ChartKick with WickedPDF.  See https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/343 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342516/chartkick-charts-do-not-show-when-rendering-to-pdf-using-wicked-pdf and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663173/rails-4-pdfkit-failed-converting-chartkick-graph-to-pdf